# Angular 13 - Drag and drop is not working with ngFor -json array

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I'm giving my very 1st attempt with Angular material CDK drag and drop for one my user story.

I don't understand why array of object is not working in cdk drag and drop

> Argument of type 'CdkDragDrop<{ id: number; imgSrc: string; name:
> string; }[], any, any>' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'CdkDragDrop<string[], string[], any>'.   The types of
> 'container.data' are incompatible between these types.
> Type '{ id: number; imgSrc: string; name: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.

I'm trying to drag image from below data source

```
items = [
    {
      id: 0,
      imgSrc: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080',
      name: 'Color B',
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      imgSrc: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF',
      name: 'Color R',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      imgSrc: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150/FFFF00/000000',
      name: 'Color L',
    },
  ]; // drag from this source
```

Drop it to my empty location

```
basket = [] // drop items here
```

my scenario is to load API response in `item=[]` and do drag and drop it to my `basket = []` then submit the reactive form.

I changed [this official straight forward example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-astsr3)  as per my requirement. But getting above mentioned error. Since its very first start I don't know how to fix this issue.

Kindly help me on this.

Thanks to all

Facing below issue in my local even after `imported dragNdrop module`
[image: facing in my local]

Comment: Where is code for ngFor?

Comment: its there in my statackbliz @Vega

Comment: No, the code should be in the post and not in external links nor in images

Comment: Please read [ask] and take a [tour]

Comment: @Vega I'll keep this in my mind and follow the same in future. forgive now.. I'm not using SO frequently

Comment: The thing is SO is not about users, but content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed your stackblitz sample. See [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-astsr3-hs217d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-disabled-sorting-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-disabled-sorting-example.ts).

First, define `Item` interface.

```
interface Item {
  id: number;
  imgSrc: string;
  name: string;
}
```

Then you have to define `items` and `baskets` as `Item[]`.

```
items: Item[] = [
  :
];

basket: Item[] = [];
```

And your `drop` argument should be `Item[]`.

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<Item[]>) {
  :
}
```

Comment: Could you explain me how its working now?.. it would help me understand and go further in future. what is the expectation here to make it work?

Comment: @Flavio, the error you got it says that the arguments that you call to the function is not the argument of the function. The variable "event" type CdkDragDrop<T> (or CdkDragEnter<T>, or CdkDragExit<T>, or ...) the "T" should match -. This happens always you see a type `SomeClass<T>` -you should reemplace the "T" by a concrete type-. More about [generic types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#hello-world-of-generics)

Comment: @Eliseo i've updated my question, im getting issue in local even after `imported` `dragndrop module` in my feature module

Comment: @Flavio, the type of the variable you  use in  `[cdkDropListData]` of **both** cdkDropList should be the same (your "basket" variable has no type), and is the type you use in the argument of the function: `event: CdkDragDrop<..here you type..>`. It's the reason to use Interfaces (if the types are not string[] or number[] or whatever. You always can use `event: CdkDragDrop<any>` but it's not advisable (nor friendly). You can also not use interface and write some like:`basket:{id:number,imgSrc:string,name:string}[] = []` and `drop(event: CdkDragDrop<{id:number,imgSrc:string,name:string}[]>)`